# Why does has my javascript stopped working on live site, but works fine in test environment?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, this is very weird...

http://connecttofriends.com/admin/login

I'm writing an administration control panel and am using a template from Theme Forest (because I didn't sign on to create any graphics, so my client bought it). For the login page listed above, I had to program it to run through Javascript due to the way it was set up.

I got it working and everything. Suddenly, though, something bizarre happened, and Javascript has not worked on that page at all since. None of my Javascript will even appear in Firebug, and I haven't been able to find anything to suggest that there's a Javascript error. Worse yet... on my local test server, it works perfectly fine. It just refuses to work on the live server for whatever reason.

Has anything like this ever happened before? How can I possibly fix this? I can't find anything wrong, and it works fine on my test server. I've at least been able to continue development on the test server, but without the live version working its useless.

I'll post code if people ask, but I don't see much of a reason to under these circumstances because the code actually works.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: GET http://connecttofriends.com/admin/js/jquery-1.7.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Just checking your page and looked at the javascript console and it appears to me that jQuery is not loading.  You could also use the CDN hosted jQuery http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Comment: I suggest you link to the jquery files hosted by google here http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/

Comment: jQuery was originally loaded through CDN, and it wasn't working then, either. No idea why, but it was working locally as well. Turns out, I did forget to upload the latest version I had downloaded, and it works now... but it still doesn't explain why it suddenly stopped working when I loaded Google Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't load.

It tries to fetch jQuery from this address: http://connecttofriends.com/admin/js/jquery-1.7.min.js, and it's not there. Missing a `/`, to indicate root?

Comment: Ugh... okay, to clarify, that jQuery was originally being loaded through Google Code. It still wasn't working then, so I downloaded the latest copy of jQuery, but I guess I forgot to upload it. I'll do that and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Okay, the issue is fixed now... I forgot to upload the file, it seems, but again, it was doing the same thing when I was using Google Apix. When I switched over to using a local file it appeared to be doing the same thing... I guess I just wasn't thinking straight because this control panel has been bugging the crap out of me when this issue first occurred... thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

the path you using is not loading, why dont you use jquery link as https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js

this'll also reduce your server hits.

Comment: It was originally programmed to do that. JSView even told me it was loading, and I opened it up through JSView and I could view all the source code, but it still did the same thing then. I changed it to a local version of jQuery and forgot to upload the file, so that's why it wasn't working when I switched. -_- Weird thing is that it worked locally yesterday through that link, but not on the live server...

Answer (score 0):

jquery library is not getting loaded.Please check the path of the jquery-1.7.min.js.